How can I generate a random number on Solana?
Wanted to know the best way to generate random numbers on anchor.
I heard about oracles and switchboard but also heard on candy machine v2.
What would be the most efficient way to generate a random number?
If you can provide documentation would be very helpful!
Thanks

Depends on what you need the random numbers for.
A little primer on blockchains is that they need to be deterministic and replayable, meaning we cannot achieve true randomness on-chain. For example, Imagine having two validators running your program and they both call the function to generate a random number. Which number will be picked? How can the transaction be replayed?
There are a few ways to achieve pseudo-randomness on-chain.

Trivially using a predictable randomness algorithm like Metaplex does with the candy machine

    let recent_slothashes = &ctx.accounts.recent_slothashes;
    let data = recent_slothashes.data.borrow();
    let most_recent = array_ref![data, 12, 8];


    let clock = Clock::get()?;
    // seed for the random number is a combination of the slot_hash - timestamp
    let seed = u64::from_le_bytes(*most_recent).saturating_sub(clock.unix_timestamp as u64);


    let remainder: usize = seed
        .checked_rem(candy_machine.data.items_available - candy_machine.items_redeemed)
        .ok_or(CandyError::NumericalOverflowError)? as usize;

GH Link
Safer ways to achieve this making it hard for attackers to exploit your program

Use a Verifiable Number Generator like Switchboard, Switchboard Tutorial or Orao, Calyptus Orao Tutorial


In this case is for a lottery, I head switchboard is a good choice but also heard of candymachine v2? is it good?

Candy machine uses a combination of the slot_hash - timestamp to select the next item to mint, see https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/1252b60a23f1b1ee924da2c40c702af5c8ff646a/candy-machine-core/program/src/instructions/mint.rs#L62. Candy Machine is not a PRNG library

Note that getrandom isn't supported on-chain. You'll likely need to dummy it out in some way if you use it https://solana.com/docs/programs/lang-rust#depending-on-rand
